# production server dont show images

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Can you help me? Here is my server. http://46.101.160.4/
In header-courusel i should have images, but he is not display. here is my code :

## index.html.erb

```
          <!-- THE FIRST SLIDE-->
        <li>
          <!-- FIRST SLIDE OVERLAY -->
          <div class="slider_overlay"></div> 
          <!-- FIRST SLIDE MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/doroga1.jpg" />
          <!-- FIRST SLIDE CAPTION-->
          <div class="slider_caption">
            <h2>Пассажирские перевозки <br>Донбасс - Крым </h2>
            <p>Ежедневно в обе стороны</p>             
          </div>
        </li>
```

here is my style.css.scss

```
.slider_area{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }
.slider_overlay {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0.8;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 9;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

on your server app directory

along with this set

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your environment/production.rb

Comment: To the server deployed code on vps.After setting this to true don,t forget to restart your server

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /home/deploy/tandem/releases/20161117120854/config/environments/production.rb:38)

Comment: you can rename changeconfig.serve_static_assets to config.serve_static_files.which version of rails are you using?

Comment: your image says you are using assets/orange.jpg instead of assets you need to use /assets

Comment: you need to rename all the assets/ with /assets/ is your orange.png showing now

Comment: i dont understand what you mean :(

Comment: suppose you are writing assets/orange.png replace it with /assets/orange.png if its assets/orange2.png replace it with /assets/orange2.png and so on.. for orange3,4 or whatever

Comment: all work. i just remove /assets and standalone only orange1... etc. thx a lot